# Split time series into several daily plots in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, ggtimeseries

I have a large time series of temperature observations that I am attempting to visualize using ggplot in R. The temperature observations were collected at 20-minute intervals over a period of months resulting in 9048 data points. I can visualize the entire time series, but I would like to visualize the data by having a plot for each day in order to analyze any fine-scale features in my dataset.

I was able to plot the first day of data using the code below, but I do not know how to best go about setting up a loop or using another technique to split up the rest of the data easily so they can be plotted. Am I overthinking this?

```
p <- ggplot(Kappa_Temp,aes(x=TIME_UTC,y=TEMPERATURE))+
   geom_line(color="red")+
   geom_point(color="red")+
   xlab("")+
   theme_ipsum()+
   theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))+
   scale_x_datetime(limit=c(TIME_UTC[1],TIME_UTC[72]))
 p
```

Comment: Could you share the image of `p` to see what you want to visualise?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `date` variable to indicate the date/day, and use `lapply()` to loop over each of the unique `date` values, like this:

```
Kappa_Temp <- Kappa_Temp %>% mutate(date= as.Date(TIME_UTC))

plots <- lapply(unique(Kappa_Temp$date), function(d) {
  ggplot(Kappa_Temp %>% filter(date == d),aes(x=TIME_UTC,y=TEMPERATURE))+
    geom_line(color="red")+
    geom_point(color="red")+
    xlab("")+
    theme_ipsum()+
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))
})
```

`plots` is now a list of plots, with one plot for each day.

You could also use `facet_wrap(~day, scales="free")` to see multiple dates at one time; Note that this will create one facet for each day, so you may have to add some constraint to the `data` input to `ggplot()` to limit the number of facets (i.e. may be too many to look at one time).

```
ggplot(Kappa_Temp,aes(x=TIME_UTC,y=TEMPERATURE))+
  geom_line(color="red")+
  geom_point(color="red")+
  xlab("")+
  facet_wrap(~date) + 
  theme_ipsum()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))
```